# Standard home page component My Task in VisualForce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to display "Task Standard Home page component" in custom VF page.
Any one having idea for that??

Answer (score 0):

you should be more specific what you are looking for..
Basically if you want to add a VF in Homepage you should add a new custom homepage component to your homepage layout.
there is no problem displaying a list of Tasks with any query you want in VF Page.

Comment: You are not understanding my question I want to use standard component in my custom VF page

Comment: I guess you can use IFrame to display standard screen if this is what you are looking for..